# Can I play windows mediaplayer video in android?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-mediaplayer

I mean I want to play a video in my webview in android e.g :

```
 <embed src="http://www.sample.url" height="480" width="640" autostart="1" 
loop="1"align="absmiddle" type="application/x-mplayer2" 
pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/download/default.asp" 
showcontrols="0" showdisplay="0" showstatusbar="0">
```

This does not work in android? 
How can I use it to work on android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android only supports certain Video File Formats. Im pretty sure WMV is not one of them. You will need to install a custom Video Player, or write one yourself which can decode the WMV file